# Xamarin.Forms - Is there a way to disable Pull to refresh if webView contains opened Modal or Menu on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, webview, pull-to-refresh

I've recently implemented xamarin's `RefreshView` over `WebView` control in my app to produce pull-to-refresh action, but I doesn`t cover disabling of refresh action, when I open a fixed element left menu or jQuery modal. Both modal and menu are already implemented in viewed website.

I`ve done some testing and WkWebView in iOS app seems to be OK with this functionality and most of well-known browser have this covered too. I am only having this issue in Android app.

I have also tried adding some `overscroll-behavarior` to the body tag of the website, but it seems that the behavior is made only for refresherer implementation on the web.

Does anybody have any idea? ? I`ll be glad for anything.

```
<RefreshView
      x:Name="RefreshLayout"
      Command="{Binding RefreshCommand, Source={x:Reference WebViewPageName}}"
      IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Source={x:Reference WebViewPageName}}"
      RefreshColor="{StaticResource Color}">

      <extensions:ScrolledWebView 
           x:Name="webView"
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            
</RefreshView>
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent a RefreshView from responding to swipe gestures, [set the `IsEnabled` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/refreshview#disable-a-refreshview) to `False` when you want solely the web content to receive the swipe gesture.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I am thinking about this one, it just requires handling open/close events. I am just curious if there is any other solution.

Comment: If you're referring to another way to prevent the RefreshView from stealing swipe gestures, no, there is not another solution in Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the IsEnabled property with a flag,  the flag value is based on the state of menu or modal in your app.